# Has anyone interfaced Neo4j to Knime?

Tags: neo4j, knime

Has anyone interfaced [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) to [Knime](http://www.knime.org)?

Answer (score 1):

I asked them if they'd be interested in a technology integration.

Comment: No news since? That'd bee great actually.

Comment: Hey Pierre, sorry my bad, I started the convo but dropped the ball due to lack of capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Knime now has some REST extensions:
https://tech.knime.org/book/krest-rest-nodes-for-knime-trusted-extension

These will allow data to be pushed to/from Neo4J.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access Neo4J via JDBC:
[https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/connection-to-neo4j-possible](http://link)